# How to better ask my question over at C.SE here?

Tags: discussion, support

How better to rework [my question over at C.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/revisions/35233/4), which I reproduce below, so that I may get one other authoritative interpretation other than the plain reading of the text? I would like the authoritative interpretation from BH, if one can be found.

> The following scriptural verses and its plain reading were presented
>   in [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/what-is-the-biblical-argument-that-homosexual-attraction-is-sinful-as-opposed/35238#35238) to [What is the biblical argument that homosexual
>   *attraction* is sinful (as opposed to just lust)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35233/what-is-the-biblical-argument-that-homosexual-attraction-is-sinful-as-opposed)
>
> > I believe the answer if in **Trial and Temptation** [James 1:12-18
> >     (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%201%3A12-18&version=RSVCE), the relevant parts being vv. 12-15:
> >
> > > **12** Blessed is the man who endures trial, for when he has stood the test he will receive the crown of life which God has promised to
> > >       those
> > >       who love him. **13** Let no one say when he is tempted, “I am tempted
> > >       by God”; for God cannot be tempted with evil and he himself tempts no
> > >       one; **14** but each person is tempted when he is lured and enticed by
> > >       his own desire. **15** Then desire when it has conceived gives birth
> > >       to sin; and sin when it is full-grown brings forth death.
> >
> > It is not sin until v. 15:
> >
> > > **15** Then desire when it has conceived gives birth to sin[.]
> >
> > Before then it is a a temptation for them, a trial that scripture
> >     calls to them to endure.
>
> What other authoritative interpretations are there other than the one
>   provided by the plain reading of the text?
>
> ---
>
> **Please note** that only ONE other authoritative interpretation is needed to answer this question.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'authoritative'? 2) We stick to the 'plain meaning' of the text here in its *original* context, not as interpreted by later religious groups - if that's not what you're looking for, you should probably look elswhere; 3) [Be sure to read our site distinctives.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: But to ask it here, you would simply ask, "What does this text mean?" Then give the text. If you're looking for a theology of sin and culpability, this is not the place.

Comment: @majnemɪzdæn Thank you! You have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You've got some potentially interesting dots to connect, but (I would suggest) associating this with SSA is a pointless distraction -- or worse than pointless, as it introduces a "[red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)" (i.e., logically misleading).

It seems to me that James 1:15 is the could be the essence of a question, in *something* like these terms:

> The metaphor of 'birth' is used in James 1:15 to elaborate the process of temptation, and points to a moment when 'desire' becomes 'sin'. But this leaves the relationship of inclination and act otherwise undefined. What, then, is the relationship between them?

Even that is a bit inadequate, and includes some questionable assumptions. But as further "dots" that might inform a biblical response, one could include:

- [Genesis 3:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+3%3A6&version=NASB;WLC)
- [Exodus 20:17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+20%3A17&version=NASB;WLC) // [Deuteronomy 5:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deut+5%3A21&version=NASB;WLC)
- [Jeremiah 17:9-10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah+17%3A9-10&version=NASB;WLC)
- [Matthew 5:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+5%3A28&version=NASB;SBLGNT)
- [Romans 7:7-10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+7%3A7-10&version=NASB;SBLGNT)

Each one of those texts, each in a different way, "problematizes" the sin/desire connection -- or so it seems to me.

I don't know how much help this is in framing your question. But [@majnemɪzdæn's comment](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/how-to-better-ask-my-question-over-at-c-se-here#comment3633_1109) is the BH.SE bottom line. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Leaving aside SSA and focusing only the text, there is no way going around v. 15 which tells us **when** sin comes to be.